# Upload your own profile picture

Tags: java, android, picasso

When I start the application, I upload an image using Picasso to imageview. I'm trying to make the user upload their own image. If I take a picture or select it from the gallery, I can display it in an imageview. But I would like to use SharedPreferences to display the image the next time I load the application, which I unfortunately can't do.
Here is my code.

```
private void showImageOptionDialog(){
        final String[] options = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.image_options);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_title)
                .setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        switch (which){
                            case 0:
                                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent();
                                cameraIntent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 11);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                intent.setType("image/*");
                                startActivityForResult(intent, 9);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                SaveSharedPreference.setAvatar(context, "none");
                                recreate();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        //Check if the intent was to pick image, was successful and an image was picked
        if(requestCode == 9 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){

            //Get selected image uri from phone gallery
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            //Display selected photo in image view
            //head_image.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            assert selectedImage != null;
            SaveSharedPreference.setAvatar(context, selectedImage.toString());
        }
        //Handle camera request
        else if(requestCode == 11 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){

            //We need a bitmap variable to store the photo
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) Objects.requireNonNull(data.getExtras()).get("data");

            //Display taken picture in image view
            head_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        recreate();
    }
```

Then I try to load using

```
Picasso.get()
                .load(SaveSharedPreference.getAvatar(context))
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .transform(new CropCircleTransformation())
                .into(head_image);
```

Thank you for your help

(application runs on Android 7.0+)

Answer (score 0):

It's NOT a good idea to save a photo using `SharedPreferences`. Try caching it or use a local Database or File system to store and/or restore them